# Seeking alternative strategy for forming assortative network in netlogo

Tags: social-networking, netlogo

In my netlogo simulation, I have a population of turtles that have several sociologically-relevant attributes (e.g., gender, race, age, etc.). I want them to form a network that is assortative on multiple of these attributes. The strategy that I’ve been trying to use to accomplish this is to: (i) form all possible links among the turtles, (ii) calculate a propensity to pair index for each of these “potential” links which is a weighted linear combination of how similar two turtles on the relevant attributes, and (iii) then run a modified version the “lottery” code from the models library so that links with higher propensities to pair are more likely to be selected, the selected links are then set to be “real” and all the potential links that didn’t win the lottery (i.e., are not set to real) are deleted. The problem that I’m running into is that forming all possible links in the first steps is causing me to run out of memory. I’ve done everything I can to maximize the memory that netlogo can use on my system, so this question isn’t about memory size. Rather, it’s about modeling strategy. I was wondering whether anyone might have a different strategy for forming a network that is assortative on multiple turtle attributes without having to form all potential links. The reason I was forming all potential links was because it seemed necessary to do so in order to calculate a propensity to pair index to use in the lottery code, but I’m open to any other ideas and any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I’m including a draft of the modified version of the lottery code I’ve been working, just in case it’s helpful to anyone, but it may be a little tangential since my question is more about strategy than particular coding issues. Thank you!

```
to initial-pair-up
ask winning-link [set real? true]
end

to-report winning-link
let pick random-float sum [propensitypair] of links  
let winner nobody 
ask not real? links 
[if winner=nobody
[ifelse similarity > pick
        [set winner self] [set pick pick-similarity] ] ] 
report winner
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a "lottery" problem, I would normally suggest using the [Rnd extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Rnd-Extension#netlogo-rnd-extension), but I suspect it would not help you here, because you would still need to create a list of all propensity pairs which would still be too big.

So, assuming that you have a `propensity` reporter (for which I've put a dummy reporter below) here is one way that you could avoid blowing up the memory:

```
to create-network [ nb-links ]
  ; get our total without creating links:
  let total 0
  ask turtles [
    ask turtles with [ who > [ who ] of myself ] [
      set total total + propensity self myself
    ]
  ]
  ; pre-pick all winning numbers of the lottery:
  let picks sort n-values nb-links [ random-float total ]
  let running-sum 0
  ; loop through all possible pairs...
  ask turtles [
    if empty? picks [ stop ]
    ask turtles with [ who > [ who ] of myself ] [
      if empty? picks [ stop ]
      set running-sum running-sum + propensity self myself
      if first picks < running-sum [
        ; ...and create a link if we have a winning pair
        create-link-with myself
        set picks but-first picks
      ]
    ]
  ]
end

to-report propensity [ t1 t2 ]
  ; this is just an example, your own function is probably very different
  report
    (1 / (1 + abs ([xcor] of t1 - [xcor] of t2))) +
    (1 / (1 + abs ([ycor] of t1 - [ycor] of t2)))
end
```

I have tried it with 10000 turtles:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10000 [
    set xcor random-xcor
    set ycor random-ycor
  ]
  create-network 1000
end
```

It takes a while to run, but it doesn't take take much memory.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. This is super helpful. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I have misunderstood, but I am unclear why you need to have the (potential) link established to run your lottery code. Instead, you could calculate the propensity for a pair of nodes (nodeA and nodeB) and create a link between them if the random-float is lower than the propensity. If you want it proportional to the 'share' of the propensity, calculate the total propensity over all pairs first and then the probability of creating the link is this-pair-propensity / total-propensity.

Then the only issue is running through each pair exactly once. The easiest way is probably an outer loop (nodeA) of all agents and an inner loop of agents (nodeB) with a who number that is greater than the outer loop asker (myself). Something like:

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 30
  [ set xcor random-xcor
    set ycor random-ycor
  ]

  ask turtles
  [ ask turtles with [ who > [who] of myself ]
    [ if random-float 1 < 0.4 [create-link-with myself]
    ]
  ]
end
```